# Windows explorer stops showing PDF's in the preview pane

Tags: windows-7, pdf, windows-explorer, adobe-acrobat

Some users in our office use the preview pane in the windows explorer to view PDF's. After a while (~an hour) the preview pane no longer shows the preview.

- On one PC, it says "No preview available" (even though there should be)
- On another PC, the preview pane simply just stays blank.

All PCs have Adobe Reader XI, and one has Adobe Acrobat XI as well.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Currently, the users have to "hot seat" to continue their work.

**NOTE -** these files all *do* have previews, as when the users switch PCs, they are able to see the previews that were previously "unavailable" on the first PC.

**EDIT:** After some investigation, the PC's don't seem to be running hot, the memory isn't running exceptionally high, and the memory seems to be sitting comfortably at ~50%. They are using additional programs at the same time, but that doesn't seem to affect this. (It still runs slowly with out any other programs running)

**EDIT 2:** File size does not seem to affect the process in any way. A 500 KB file might take 2 minutes to load, whereas a 5 MB file might only take 30 seconds. I also found that during this process, there is 4 instances of Adobe Reader running, anywhere between 4,000 and 300,000 MB of memory. When I stop these processes, if I have a file I am attempting to view, it just automatically restarts the processes, but if I have already loaded a preview, the processes end, but the preview disappears.

**UPDATE:** After a little digging and research, I have discovered this may be being caused by a buildup in temporary memory, so I have created a dll that (should) empty the unused RAM. -- No change.

**EDIT 3:** Users do multiple things on the PC, like using MicroStation and Photoshop. For most of the process it will sit ~1 GB memory, then unexpectedly spike. Resetting the PC will unload the memory partially, making it crash sooner (~45 mins).

The PC usually sits idle overnight (hibernation) but on the weekend it gets shutdown.

Comment: What happens if you restart explorer?

Comment: No change. I got lucky once just by hitting F5 (Refresh), but that only worked once. It usually takes a while for the system to "recover". I also checked the temperature of the machines but they weren't hot at all. They also run in an air conditioned office

Comment: I would be very surpsised if this was temperature related ;)

Comment: Is Acrobat/Reader running when you encounter these effects?

Comment: Did you try to reset the .pdf file extension/application association? Possibly it was modified by another application.

Comment: @MaxWyss I checked the Processes in the Task Manager, and there was 2 instances of `Adobe Reader` (one running at ~92,000 K and the other running at ~4,500 K memory), and an instance of `Adobe Reader & Adobe Acrobat Manager` running at ~3,000 K memory

Comment: @user3169 I'm not sure that's relevant. They are still associated with Adobe Reader, and Acrobat - if they open the file, it will automatically open in Reader. The issue is viewing the preview in the Windows Explorer preview pane

Comment: @Ben: What happens when you kill off the Adobe Reader process(es)? Will the preview then work?

Comment: @MaxWyss When I kill the processes, another just starts up immediately. Especially for Adobe Reader. This seems to slow down the process even more while this is happening.

Comment: Instead of the bloated Adobe, you could use [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/addons.php).

Comment: I'm wondering if there could be one corrupt PDF that's blocking the Acrobat process(es). Preview would work fine until Windows decides to access the hypothetical bad PDF. Then the process creating the previews would hang and no more previews would be displayed. Killing the process would cause a retry of the bad preview and the same block. (That's wild speculation of course, although I know for a fact that you can get Adobe Reader to hang with some PDF constructs)

Comment: @user2543253: That should be easy to test by killing & restarting Explorer or alternatively by logging out & in. If this solves the problem then it's the Adobe preview plug-in that's hanging.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I'm 99% sure that it's Adobe's shell extension misbehaving and Explorer restart with `taskkill explorer` should fix that for the time being.

Comment: @harrymc we have tried killing processes, and even restarting the PC, to no effect. We haven't killed explorer, but shouldn't restarting/resetting affect that?

Comment: Is this issue is x64 specific? If yes, try this fix: [Fixes for 64-bit Adobe Reader preview handler and thumbnails](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/index.html)

Comment: Your post is unclear: (1) Does "restarting"="rebooting"? (2) Is the only effect of the problem a blank preview screen in Explorer? (3) Some more information is required about the situation when the problem appears, such as screenshots from Task Manager regarding memory and CPU usage.

Comment: @harrymc 1) No, restarting != rebooting, but I have tried both, to the same effect. 2) No, but I believe it may be caused by the same thing. What that thing is, I am unsure. 3) I will edit the question and add the additional information.

Comment: If the problem persists across reboots, then this is a very different problem from a bad PDF file, unless it only returns when one tries to preview the same folder (does it?). When posting the Task Manager screenshots, please check if the situation is identical after the reboot (if not, post more screenshots).

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs because you must open another instance of the program to preview the document.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\DetailsContainer]
"DetailsContainer"=hex:02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer]
"DetailsContainerSizer"=hex:24,01,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2b,03,00,00
```

Then do the following for both keys:

- Right click the key
- Select `Permissions`
- Select your name
- Check `Deny`

**References**

- [Solution to Windows 7 Preview Pane Size Problem](http://www.johandraaisma.nl/solution-to-windows-7-preview-pane-size-problem/)
- [How to set different Windows 7 Explorer layouts for different windows (with/without navigation pane)](https://superuser.com/questions/627114/)
- [How to Register a Preview Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144144)
- [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)
- [Acrobat Pro X PDF previewing not working in Windows 7 64-bit](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1182272)
- [Acrobat Preview Handler Windows Server 2012](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1260364)
- [How to Enable the Preview of PDF Files in 64-bit Windows 7](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1231685)
- [Why doesn't PDF Preview Handler Work?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1414821)
- [PDF and XFDF file associations](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/850944)
- [Thumbnails Missing in Vista Explorer Large & Extra Large View](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/391715)
- [PDF Icons used to Show Preview of Document - Now it shows PDF Icon](https://forums.adobe.com/message/1872451)
- [Acrobat Cleaner](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html)
- [Known issues | Acrobat XI, Reader XI](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/known-issues-acrobat-xi-reader.html)

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately. I only get a file preview for bitmap images in the preview pane of Windows Explorer. Previewing does not work for all documents like Word, PDF, Text etc.. Thumbnails however are created and displayed correctly for all documents in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this fixed the "No Preview Available." problem for me with Windows 7 Pro x64:

1. Open Acrobat Pro X
2. Go to Edit > Preferences > General
3. At the bottom
   of page Select Default PDF Handler. I chose Adobe Pro X and click
   apply.

Source: [http://answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-viewing-pdf-files-in-preview-pane/6d313151-136d-4315-9e91-24c0661ecb22)

Answer (score 1):

When the preview suddenly stops working (but has worked in the past)... Use Ctrl-Alt-Delete to start the Task Manager.  Click on the Processes tab.  End the "AcroRd32" processes (close Acrobat processes).  Click on a new pdf in Windows explorer and it should now show up in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while using AVG PC Tuneup. AVG would put the app to "sleep" which would prevent it from showing the prview of the PDF file in the preview pane.

1. Open AVG PC Tuneup and "wake" Adobe Acrobat Reader.
2. Open Task Manager and kill acroread32 and any Adobe Acrobat Reader processes

Should work now.

Comment: Not really. My answer addresses this problem **specifically** for users of AVG PC Tuneup. Simply killing acoread32 won't fix the problem. AVG PC Tuneup will de-prioritize a process in order to speed up your PC. "Waking" the process (if this is your issue) will likely fix the preview pane issue.  Killing acroread32 was for good measure. That process will start again next time you try to preview a PDF.